# If the iterated series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_{ij}|$ converges, does $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ converge for each fixed col. $j$?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

We are given a doubly indexed array of real numbers $\{a_{ij} : i,j \in \mathbb{N}\}$.
Let $i$ denote the row index and $j$ denote the column index.

I will try to prove the following statement: If the iterated series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_{ij}|$ converges, then for each fixed column $j$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ converges to some real number $c_j$.

**Proof Attempt**: We are given that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_{ij}|$$ converges. This means that for each fixed row $i \in \mathbb{N}$, the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_{ij}|$ converges to some real number $b_i$, and the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i$ converges as well.

Because every term in the array is positive, we have for each fixed $j \in \mathbb{N}$,$$0 \leq |a_{ij}| \leq b_i \hspace{20 pt} (eq. 1)$$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i$ converges, for each fixed column $j$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_{ij}|$ converges by the Comparison Test. By the Absolute Convergence Test, for each fixed column $j$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ converges to some real number $c_j$.

**Commentary**: I am unsure about the validity of equation 1. I'm assuming that if we have a convergent infinite series $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... = A$ where $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n \leq A$. I'll try to prove this too.

Proof: Let $(s_m)$ be the sequence of partial sums of the convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = A$ where $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, $(s_m)$ is a monotone, increasing sequence. We first want to show that $s_m \leq A$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that there exists an $m_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_{m_0} > A$. Because $(s_m)$ is increasing, all the terms after $s_{m_0}$ must be greater than A. So the limit of $(s_m)$ can't be A as it is an increasing sequence. This is a contradiction. So, $s_m \leq A$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$. And, because any single term $a_n$ is apart of some partial sum $s_m$ with $s_m \leq A$, we have $a_n \leq s_m \leq A$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: MathJax tip: If you wish to tag an equation, try using the `\tag{}` command. For example, `$$1 + 1 = 2 \tag{Eq. $1$}$$` produces:$$1 + 1 = 2 \tag{Eq. $1$}$$

Answer (score 2):

All the proof is correct. Everything is fine.

P.S.: if you want, try to prove that, in this case,
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}| = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$$
And what if we remove the absolute value?
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$$
What if the series is not absolutely convergent but only conditionally convergent? Are the previous results true?